# C# automation over RDP

Tags: c#, automation, rdp

I have a windows network (not connected to domain) and I need to provide some automation on each PC at certain time of the day. There are several tasks - launch executables, managing FS, transfering files. All this actions must be implemented via RDP, using C#. What is common approach to achieve this? I don't have experience using RDP within software. So are there .NET classes or free libraries I can use to get RDP functionality in my software. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All the tasks you have listed relyed much more on security issues for machines within your network and a user logged-in priveledges a rather than a usage of RPD.
Within a windows domain the tasks like yours are usually delegated to ActiveDirectory administration and policies.

In case of a not Windows Domain Network you will need to use a mechanism that will be presented in following configuration:

- a client installed on each particular machine under proper permissions. The client should implement a *subscriber* pattern.
- a server installed on a "commander" machine. the server should inplement a *publisher* pattern.

There should be a lot of ready solution that should implement the concept of content disribution and starting specific scripts. I think that your investment in such tools research and evaluation will be much more time- and cost- effective rather than writing an app that *"uses RPD functionality"*

But if there is a reason that prevents usage of 3rd parties, I would go for implementaion of WCF service that will be installed on all clients. This service should be *"trained"* to do all your suff on client. Server side you will need an appliaction or a service that will publish events for clients or trigger known clients methods.

Comment: We can do all the things manually using RDP client to access other machines, so I think it's possible to automate everyting using proper RDP api, but I didn't find proper example with comments, what interface I should use and what library I need to include to my project.